# How in .net do I enable cookies with HttpClient to work with Cloudflare's 403 status code and "Please enable cookies."?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, httpclient, cloudflare

I've been using GetSling.com's API for several years, but recently they've been making several changes that is making life much more difficult. I am trying to login a user into the API using the C# .Net code below.

At first the response returned a status code of 403 Forbidden and a message of "**Unsupported web browser, please use something else**", so I added

```
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Other/0.0.1");
```

and that made it a little happier.

But it was now saying "**Please enable cookies.**". I tried to enable cookies by adding a CookieContainer to HttpClientHandler and HttpClient. The 403 Forbidden status code persists. Apparently GetSling.com is now using a Cloudflare service that is triggered by using .Net to access their API. If I use the same hit using curl it works great.

```
    curl -X POST "https://api.getsling.com/v1/account/login" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"email\":\"123@abc.com\",\"password\":\"xxxx\"}"
```

The text of the full error message:

> Please enable cookies.
>
> You are unable to access api.getsling.com
>
> Why have I been blocked?
>
> This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.
>
> What can I do to resolve this?
>
> You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.

Here is the C# .Net code I am trying to use to enable cookies and access the account/login API hit.

```
    string Json = string.Format("{{\"email\":\"{0}\",\"password\":\"{1}\"}}",
        Email.Trim(),
        Password.Trim());
    StringContent Content = new StringContent(Json);
    Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        clientHandler.UseCookies = true;
    
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Other/0.0.1");                
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.getsling.com");
        HttpResponseMessage Response = await client.PostAsync("/v1/account/login", Content);
    }
```

I'll try to email GetSling.com with the Cloudflare Ray ID as suggested in the error page text, but I doubt that will go very far.

Has anyone else had to deal with something similar?

Thanks,
Russ

Answer (score 0):

I saw that kind of error in Cloudflare, and in my case it was the issue with too strictly configured Managed Challenge: https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-firewall-rules/cloudflare-challenges/#cloudflare-challenges

Because that domain in Cloudflare was under my control I updated rules and thats it.

And since we don't know how that rules were configure we can't do anything with that, only wait answer from support.

Also you can check this advices, maybe something from that will help you:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/getstarted/concepts/cloudflare-challenges/